# sharing one instance throughout the application

Tags: c#, object, multiple-instances

I have to create multiple instance of a particular class throughout the lifecycle of the application.

My problem is , I want to share one of my class instances throughout the application to be able to change the state of the variable within the class.

I can't use singleton, since I do need to create multiple instances.

Comment: Use a static property to expose the shared instance, same as you would with a singleton

Comment: A dependency injection container would solve this issue for you.